# What was the biggest actor-actress height mismatch in a romantic feature film?

Tags: casting, romance

It is a well-known fact that lead actor-actress pairings have not always resulted in good height matches. What was the biggest actor-actress height mismatch in a romantic feature film? (comedies/farces do not count)

To get this question started I submit the following still:

[image: Tom Cruise with Kelly McGillis]

Notice that in the shot Cruise is standing one inch higher than McGillis, even though in reality he is two inches shorter than her.

(Note that by a "mismatch" I am referring to the situation where the man is shorter than the woman. When men are taller, that is the normal situation.)

Comment: Based on your example, I'm assuming you mean where the female is shorter? Also, I'm having trouble not voting to close this as "trivia"... can you explain why you think it's anything other than trivia?

Comment: Female is taller... *sigh* trying to do too many things at once.

Comment: *"Cruise is standing one inch higher"* All thanks to the magical Hollywood prop called an apple crate. ;)

Comment: @Walt Apple box, you mean :P And he's probably standing on a quarter apple, honestly... though it could be even a pancake.

Comment: Now I've got the song "Take My Breath Away" stuck in my head.

Comment: @BrettFromLA There's worse than having this great song in your ear.

Comment: I know you're not asking for TV series, but in Battlestar Galactica re-imaged one romance that is on display is Gaius Baltar (James Callis is 5'8") and various 6s (Trica Helpher is 5.10). It's only a couple of inches, but in some scenes it looked more dramatic than that.  In the film Moulin Rouge Ewan Mcgregor is 5'10" and Nichole Kidman is 5'11"

Answer (score 6):

One example would be the Prince movie [Under the Cherry Moon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Under_the_Cherry_Moon). He (1.58) is 10 cm smaller than Kristin Scott Thomas (1.68) (I am not American, but that must be about 3 inches). I guess there are bigger differences, but this is an example for a romantic (musical) film to start with...

If you count the relationship in Game of Thrones between Tyrion Lannister (Peter Dinklage 1.35) and Shae (Sibil Kekilli 1.63) you would have 28 cm, that's about 9 inches, but not sure if you could call this romantic ;)

I was only thinking about examples where the actress is bigger, the other way around I guess there are bigger mismatches.

Comment: While it wasn't a romantic relationship either, Sophie Turner is 16 inches taller than Dinklage - though she may have been shorter than her current 5'9" when they were a "couple"

Answer (score 5):

I'm nominating Tommy Tune as Ambrose Kemper (6'6") and Joyce Ames as Ermengarde (4'10") from the 1969 production of [Hello Dolly!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hello,_Dolly!_(film)), for a whopping difference of 1'8" (almost half a meter!) between the star crossed lovers.

[image: Tommy Tune and Joyce Ames]

Comment: That's a comedy, so it does not qualify.

Comment: @TylerDurden But is it a romantic pairing? If yes than it should apply, since any other totally artificial and undefinable constraints based just on general genre (which isn't even clearly classifyable) would seem utterly nonsensical. Afterall *Top Gun* isn't a downright romance either really.

Comment: @TylerDurden - Well it's a romantic comedy musical. Though perhaps you should fine tune what you expect by "romantic feature" in the question.

Comment: Actually, my main problem with this is that the OP's looking for a *lead actor-actress* pairing. But @TylerDurden, a *lot* of romantic movies are comedies. Rom-com is one of the biggest genres out there. If you're only looking for romantic dramas\tragedies, I'm not sure I get why.

Comment: I think the point is, if the actors were actually cast like this for comedic effect. So a romantic comedy "my dwarf boyfriend" would probably not in spirit of the question. I think the OP searches for movies where the height difference is not on purpose but rather accidental.

Comment: Good one, but fyi that's actually more than half a meter.

Comment: This is also wrong because the man is taller than the woman. A mismatch is when the woman is taller, as in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Nicole Kidman was/is 5'11" and Cruise's real life wife when they appeared together in Far And Away, which is considered a Romance film.  That bests Kelly McGillis by an inch, thereby making the biggest height difference ~3 inches.

Beyond that, it begins getting more difficult to mask the height difference, and as a taller female is not "the norm", it then turns farcical.  Any movie where Jack Black is the leading man, or Danny Devito for that matter, is more comedy than romance, and they're two of the shortest men in movies.

Comment: Well, the fake accents create a comic atmosphere, but this counts anyway.

Comment: And don't forget they met on Days of Thunder and worked together one last time in Eyes Wide Shut!

Answer (score 1):

[Amitabh Bachchan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amitabh_Bachchan) (6'2") - [Jaya Bachchan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaya_Bachchan) (5'2") with a height difference of one foot.

Yet, this pair didn't look like a mismatch. This is the reason they acted in [sixteen films together](http://www.gomolo.com/celeb/jaya-bachchan-and-amitabh-bachchan-movies-list/523/1946). As the question asks for a romantic film, then here it is.

*[Ek Nazar](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0068532/)*, *[Bansi Burji](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0068255/)* are some of the romantic films they acted together.

They are a real life pair too.

[image]

Above is the image of them in the film *Guddi*.

Comment: This is also wrong because the man is taller than the woman. A mismatch is when the woman is taller, as in the question.